# Bad performance of Threepenny-gui canvas

Tags: javascript, haskell, canvas, threepenny-gui

I tried to draw 100 animated circles with threepennt-gui. It felt kind of strange, so I made it 1000 and the problems were obvious:

- I could see the drawing (ie the canvas was black and then the circles appeared, then it went black again, etc
- It took several seconds to draw just once (and it’s supposed to draw 50 times per second (because the timer won’t let me do 60))
- every frame took incrementally longer. after a few frames it wouldn’t finish at all.

this was my code:

```
let draw (Circle c r (x:+y)) = do
        canv # set' UI.fillStyle (UI.htmlColor c)
        canv # UI.beginPath
        canv # UI.arc (x, y) r (-pi) pi
        canv # UI.closePath
        canv # UI.fill

let drawAll circles = do
        UI.clearCanvas canv
        ppos <- liftIO $ readIORef player
        draw (Circle "green" playerRadius ppos)
        mapM draw circles
```

so, I thought, maybe this generates inefficient js code ie unrolls the loop (ok, a few thousand lines should still generate and execute fairly fast)
so I converted the circles to Json and used theepenny’s ffi function like so:

```
circleToJson (Circle color radius (x:+y)) = "{c:\"" ++ color ++ "\",r:" ++ show radius ++ ",x:" ++ show x ++ ",y:" ++ show y ++ "},"

circlesToJson xs = "[" ++ (foldr (++) "" $ map circleToJson xs) ++ "]"

jsDrawFunc = "(function(canvas, circles){var ctx = canvas.getContext(\"2d\"); for (c of circles) {ctx.fillStyle=c.c; ctx.beginPath(); ctx.arc(c.x,c.y,c.r,0,2*Math.PI,true); ctx.fill();}})"

jsCanvasArg = "$(\"canvas\")[0],"

jsDrawAll circles = jsDrawFunc ++ "(" ++ jsCanvasArg ++ circlesToJson circles ++ ");"
```

and in the timer event:

```
runFunction $ ffi $ jsDrawAll circles
```

-now I could no longer see the drawing (ie all appears at once). instead firefox stopped responding to user input until drawing was finished (also, as far as I can tell, the frame-time was more consistent)-
edit: i lacked empty parentheses after beginPath, so all the circles were connected. now it’s flickering again (with 100; with 1000 it takes ~1 second to draw and doesn’t respond to user inputs).

which suggests that the canvas is the problem. (which seems confirmed after some search)

Is there a solution to that problem? (ideally one that doesn’t involve using a different gui-lib)

Comment: Threepenny really isn't designed with much focus on performance. Do you really need 1000 circles? If not – well, I suppose you can live with a bit of latency for 100-ish objects. If you do need performance, you'll have to switch to GTK/Cairo or something.

Comment: it’s not only about the not-so-little lag, but more about the fact, that i can’t see the last circles

Comment: not sure what i changed, but it stopped flickering so badly (for around 100)